# Why does Messi's 50th goal count as a record?

Tags: football, history, records, la-liga

Last night, Messi scored his 50th goal of the season.

Why is it considered a new goal-scoring record? 
Dixie Dean scored 60 goals for Everton in the FA First Division alone (he had 67 in total) in the 1927-1928 football season.

Comment: What I read in the articles, it that Messi is the first since 1931, so this does not contradict the Dixie Dean...

Comment: OK, that certainly makes sense and also remembers me why I should read newspapers from my country.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Messi had 50 goals in La Liga and another 14 goals in the Champions League, 3 goals in the Spanish Cup, 3 goals in the Spanish Supercup, 1 in the UEFA Super Cup and 2 in the Club World Cup.
Which makes 73 goals in total on 2011/2012.

Messi didn't break Dean's record but he has broken a lot of other records:

1. Most goals in one season in La Liga (previous held by Cristiano Ronaldo - 41 Goals in 2010-11)
2. Best goalscorer in history in one season in Europe (previous held by Gerd Müller - 67 goals in 1972-73)
3. Most goals in one season (previous held by Archie Stark - 70 goals in 1924-25)